# using 2 variables with sed -i

Tags: variables, sed

I'm fairly new to bash so I'm hoping this is an easy question, I'm trying to use 2 variables in a sed command but it won't work. I'm trying to insert variable b into line (variable) a:

```
a=5
b=123456
sed -i $a $b myfile.txt
```

I've tried messing with the quotes but can't get it right. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: First sort out what you'd write if the numbers were written inline in your script.  Then revise that script to replace the two numbers with variable references, remembering to use double quotes rather than single quotes.  (Hint: the syntax you're currently trying to use is completely wrong!)  You also need to identify what you mean by 'insert variable b into line a'; do you put b on a line on its own before line a, after line a, instead of line a, or do you add b to line (and then whereabouts in the line do you put it). There are different answers for each option. Also GNU vs 'classic'/POSIX?

Comment: do you want to insert 123456 on line 5, or anytime there is a 5 in your data? Small sample data and expected output would make this much easier to help with. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out that adding i to my "a" variable and the double quotes fixed it all. a=5i; b=123456; sed -i "$a $b" myfile.txt;

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but it will help for you

```
seq 10 > FileName

cat FileName 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

a=5
b=12345

sed "/$a/a$b" FileName
```

**OutPut :**

```
1
2
3
4
5
123456
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: You are most welcome , If you accept my answer ,I will get green tic :)-